# How to convert a double to its exact fractional equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, function, math, methods

In technical terms, I need a method that converts an [IEEE 754 binary64 number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) into a reduced ratio of two BigIntegers that mathematically represents exactly the same value. The method does not need to handle values that are [infinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Computing) or [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), but it does need to handle [subnormals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) and [signed zeros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). Since the IEEE 754 binary64 number format does not support representing irrational numbers, this task is theoretically possible.

Here's some examples values:

- 0.0 = 0 / 1
- -0.0 = 0 / 1
- 0.5 = 1 / 2
- 0.1 = 3602879701896397 / 36028797018963968
- 1 / (double) 3 = 6004799503160661 / 18014398509481984
- Double.MIN_NORMAL = 1 / 2^1022 = 1 / 44942328371557897693232629769725618340449424473557664318357520289433168951375240783177119330601884005280028469967848339414697442203604155623211857659868531094441973356216371319075554900311523529863270738021251442209537670585615720368478277635206809290837627671146574559986811484619929076208839082406056034304
- Double.MIN_VALUE = 1 / 2^1074 = 1 / 202402253307310618352495346718917307049556649764142118356901358027430339567995346891960383701437124495187077864316811911389808737385793476867013399940738509921517424276566361364466907742093216341239767678472745068562007483424692698618103355649159556340810056512358769552333414615230502532186327508646006263307707741093494784
- Double.MAX_VALUE = (2^1024 - 2^971) / 1 = 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368 / 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach inspects the double's bits to prevent rounding error.

In a double, first bit is the sign, the next 11 are the exponent, and the final 52 are the significand.

Instead of checking the first bit, I found it easier to just compare the whole value to 0.

Instead of getting the bits for the exponent and dealing with the exponent's sign (which is distinct from the value's sign), I use `Math.getExponent` to get its signed value. According to its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#getExponent(double)),

> - If the argument is NaN or infinite, then the result is Double.MAX_EXPONENT + 1.
> - If the argument is zero or subnormal, then the result is Double.MIN_EXPONENT -1.

If the value isn't subnormal, then the significand has an implicit leading 1 before its 52 bits. The exponent assumes that the binary point (i.e. decimal point) is after the leading 1, so I subtract 52 from the exponent to shift the binary point to the end.

```java
public static BigInteger[] convertToFraction(double value) {
  int exponent = Math.getExponent(value);
  if (exponent > Double.MAX_EXPONENT) {
    // The value is infinite or NaN.
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal parameter 'value': " + value);
  }
  long positiveSignificand;
  if (exponent < Double.MIN_EXPONENT) {
    // The value is subnormal.
    exponent++;
    positiveSignificand = Double.doubleToLongBits(value) & 0x000fffffffffffffL;
  } else {
    positiveSignificand = (Double.doubleToLongBits(value) & 0x000fffffffffffffL) | 0x0010000000000000L;
  }
  BigInteger significand = BigInteger.valueOf(value < 0 ? -positiveSignificand : positiveSignificand);
  exponent -= 52; // Adjust the exponent for an integral significand.
  BigInteger coefficient = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(Math.abs(exponent));
  if (exponent >= 0) {
    return new BigInteger[] { significand.multiply(coefficient), BigInteger.ONE };
  } else {
    BigInteger gcd = significand.gcd(coefficient);
    return new BigInteger[] { significand.divide(gcd), coefficient.divide(gcd) };
  }
}
```